# Angular ngClass evaluation method

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I might be doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.

- 1 list of tabs
- I iterate over elements in list to generate tabs. On click, I set a currentTab to the clicked element

Incriminated code is:

```
  <li ng-class="{active: !selectedTab}">
    <a href="#" ng-click="selectedTab = null;">First</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{active: selectedTab == tab}" data-ng-repeat='tab in tabs'>
    <a href="#" ng-click="selectedTab = tab;">{{tab}}</a>
  </li>
```

I simply use ngClass to set the "active" state of my tabs, and to display the appropriate content. The problem is that after first click ngClass seems to give me weird results as if my conditions '!selectedTab' and 'selectedTab == tab' end up all evaluating to 'true' since all tabs end up being active.

Here is a 'non' working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/kk2JmGSBNGVMZ6Wnu1sz?p=preview

Am I doing anything wrong or is there a bug in ngClass? If this is a bug, do you know of any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use `$parent` in the ng-repeat, because of scope differences.

```
<li ng-class="{active: $parent.selectedTab === tab}" data-ng-repeat='tab in tabs'>
  <a href="#" ng-click="$parent.selectedTab = tab;">{{tab}}</a>
</li>
```

Here's an updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tg4e3Gf3XVjhwcDuwKVG?p=preview)

Edit: as per @javaCity's comment below, using a `$scope` function to set a flag is a good alternative to using $parent as per his [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/txJvmmpwlDaZqGCWMqWD?p=preview)

### Why is this so?

For each item/iteration, ng-repeat creates a new scope, which prototypically inherits from the parent scope, but it also assigns the item's value to a new property on the new child scope. (The name of the new property is the loop variable's name.)

[image]

Image taken from, and more info available [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-repeat)

Comment: Or simply call a function instead to change the selectedTab flag. I don't like to tinker around with `$parent` but that's just my preference. Here's the plnker: http://plnkr.co/edit/txJvmmpwlDaZqGCWMqWD?p=preview

Comment: @javaCity Or that. The flag is not changed though, it's still the same flag but a different way of accessing because of inheritance. Personally I try to use as little functions as I can get away with so I do use $parent, because of the occasional snafu between `$scope` and `this` in scope functions. It's a matter of preference I guess.

Comment: @Jorg thanks I was just reading the solution on the page "Understanding scopes" from angular doc. I thought it was a ngClass problem while it is the regular scope problem! I usually never play with direct variables in the templates and always have a '.' so did not know that ngRepeat was initializing a new scope. Thank you for the great answer!